# How to understand Bash privileged mode?

Tags: bash, privileges

I've read the section in `man bash` explaining the `set` builtin's `-p` flag, and this tells me a few of the effects that privileged mode has on Bash's behavior, but it doesn't explain in enough depth (or I just don't have enough context/experience) for me to understand the purpose it serves, i.e. in what situations you would use it.

Part of my confusion comes from the fact that everything I read about privileged mode makes it sound like "under-privileged" would be a more appropriate name. This in itself is probably an indicator that I'm misunderstanding something about it.

I'm also not sure I understand setuid. I'm familiar with effective user id and real user id as it relates to `sudo`, but it sounds like setuid is a broader concept, so maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Privileged mode exists to try to increase security (by restricting potentially dangerous actions) when the shell is running under augmented privileges, such as invoked by a setuid program.

Yes, you are correct in that it sounds like "under-privileged", the `-p` option is restricting actions that could potentially allow an attack, by perhaps tricking the shell to execute commands under a more privileged user. For instance, that's why it restricts startup scripts, since those might not be owned or controlled by the privileged user in that situation. Also, inheriting functions from the environment can also be dangerous, since one could export a function such as `cd` or `ls` that might be used during the privileged shell and then trigger an action that can be used for an attack.

You also asked about "setuid". In this context, "setuid" usually refers to the permissions of binaries that includes the `04000` bit, for example permission `04711` (or `-rws--x--x` in `ls` output.) Enabling the "setuid" bit in a binary makes it always run under the effective uid of the owner of that binary. So a setuid binary owned by root will run as root whenever any user executes it. The real uid will be that of the user who invokes it, that's why the `effective uid != real uid` check is common in this situation. (BTW, the same exists for "setgid" bit, which is `02000` in file permissions.)

So one likely scenario where `bash -p` can be used is a setuid binary which runs as a privileged user (root or otherwise) and wants to spawn a shell, they might use `bash -p` for that scenario, since then bash will *try* to stay more secure (by ignoring startup scripts and functions from the environment, which might be dangerous) and will keep the permissions of the effective uid while running. Invoking it without the `-p` option means bash will simply ignore the effective uid (by resetting to the real uid) and behave as if nothing had happened...

There are still many security pitfalls here... So using a privileged bash still requires a lot of thought on how security might be impacted. The measures taken by `-p` *might* help, but need to be considered in the whole context of possible attack scenarios.

Comment: It has been almost 4 years since Shellshock.  I think that we don't need to qualify _inheriting functions from the environment can also be dangerous_ with _might be_ s and _could_ s any more.  (-: